# Find the maximizing row-column matches in a matrix

Tags: combinatorics, matrices

I have a set of R x C matrices similar to the following (can be much longer):

```
    C1      C2      C3      C4      C5      C6
R1  0.32    0.81    NA      NA      NA      NA
R2  0.90    -0.44   0.95    NA      NA      NA
R3  NA      0.93    0.86    0.24    NA      NA
R4  NA      NA      0.70    0.74    0.15    0.05
R5  NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
```

I need to find the sequence of row-columns matchings that provides the overall maximum values (when summed). Each row can be associated to one and only one column, and "cross" matchings are not allowed, i.e. if R2 was matched with C4, a following row R>2 cannot be matched with a previous column C<4.

Given the limit on crossed matching, and as the number of rows and column can be unequal, obviously not all rows and/or columns will be matched

The solution in this example would be:

```
[R2:C1 = 0.90] + [R3:C2 = 0.93] + [R4:C4 = 0.74] = 2.57
```

which is higher than alternative solutions that may contain the highest values in the matrix, such as:

```
[R2:C2 = 0.81] + [R2:C3 = 0.95] + [R4:C4 = 0.74] = 2.50
```

The only solution I came up with is to create all possible RxC matrices populated by 1 and 0 where the marginal of each row and each column is not greater than 1, and where the no-crossing rule is respected.
Then by multiplying such matrices with the original ones, I obtain new matrices containing ONLY the values in the solution, which can be easily summed.

Example of the solution above:

```
    C1  C2  C3  C4  C5  C6  |   row
R1  0   0   0   0   0   0   |   0
R2  1   0   0   0   0   0   |   1
R3  0   1   0   0   0   0   |   1
R4  0   0   0   1   0   0   |   1
R5  0   0   0   0   0   0   |   0
_______________________________
col 1   1   0   1   0   0
```

This is a valid matrix as all the marginals are <= 1 and the positioning is ordered by column = 1,2,4 and by row = 2,3,4

The problem with this solution is that as R or C grows the number of possible permutations becomes extreme.

I need to implement a general and fast solution in a software, and I can't compute millions of table each time.

Any hint will be useful, thanks!!!!

---

EDIT: This is my implementation of D.W.'s answer in pseudo code

```
result = matrix(R, C, 0) //allocate response matrix RxC with all elements = 0
for (i from 1 to R){
  for (j from 1 to C){
    part1 = A[i-1,j]
    part2 = array[j] //allocates array of length j
    for(jPrime in 1:j){
      part2[jPrime] = M[i,jPrime] + A[i-1,jPrime-1]
    }
    A[i,j] = max(part1, max(part2))
 }
}
```

This returns the following A matrix:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,] 0.32 0.81 0.81 0.81 0.81 0.81
[2,] 0.90 0.90 1.76 1.76 1.76 1.76
[3,] 0.90 1.83 1.83 2.00 2.00 2.00
[4,] 0.90 1.83 2.53 2.57 2.57 2.57
[5,] 0.90 1.83 2.53 2.57 2.57 2.57
```

Comment: Can two rows be associated to the same column?

Comment: No, each row can be associated to max one column, and vice versa, each column to only one row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem can be solved with dynamic programming in $O(RC)$ time.

I'll start by showing how to solve it in $O(RC^2)$ time.  Let $M[\cdot,\cdot]$ denote the input matrix.  Let $A[i,j]$ denote the total value of the best matching using only rows $1..i$ and columns $1..j$.  We will compute the entries of $A[\cdot,\cdot]$.  There is a recursive relation for $A[\cdot,\cdot]$:

$$A[i,j] = \max(A[i-1,j],\max\{M[i,j'] + A[i-1,j'-1] : 1 \le j' \le j\}).$$

Here the $A[i-1,j]$ term corresponds to not including any match for row $i$, and the $\max\{M[i,j'] + A[i-1,j'-1] : 1 \le j' \le j\}$ corresponds to matching row $i$ to column $j'$.

You can fill in the entries of the $A$ array in a straightforward way in $O(RC^2)$ time, and the value of the best matching is given by $A[R,C]$.  So, this gives an $O(RC^2)$ time algorithm.

You can speed this up to $O(RC)$ time by simultaneously computing another array $B[\cdot,\cdot]$, with entries defined as

$$B[i,j] = \max(A[i,1],A[i,2],\dots,A[i,j]).$$

Then all of the entries of $A$ and $B$ can be filled in, if you do it in the right order, in a total of $O(RC)$ time.  This is linear in the size of the matrix, i.e., proportional to the number of entries in the input matrix. Since any algorithm will presumably have to examine all entries in the matrix, I think that means this algorithm is asymptotically optimal: no algorithm can run faster by more than a constant factor.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand how to extract the best matches from the A[i,j] matrix, if I implement your code as in the edit above, my A is a R x C matrix which contains the "incremental best matches" but still no clear way to extract the matches

Comment: @Joram, when you fill in $A[i,j]$ by computing the max of some terms, keep track of which term which was the largest.  That helps you reconstruct what row $i$ should be matched with, and then lets you recursively look at an $A[i^*,j^*]$ term to complete the solution (with $i^*,j^*$ chosen based on which term was the largest).  To get the idea, look at a shortest-paths algorithm and how they reconstruct the shortest path (not just the length of the shortest path); it's the same idea here.

Comment: $A[i, j] = \max(A[i-1, j], A[i, j-1], A[i-1, j-1] + M[i, j])$ also works :)

Comment: @D.W. I'm currently writing a paper on the broader algorithm using this stuff. I'd like to mention you in the acknowledgments. If you prefer a proper name and affiliation (instead of DW from stackexchange) drop me a line at johann.kleinbub@gmail.com

Comment: @j_random_hacker I'm currently writing a paper on the broader algorithm using this stuff. I'd like to mention you in the acknowledgments. If you prefer a proper name and affiliation (instead of j_random_hacker from stackexchange) drop me a line at johann.kleinbub@gmail.com

Comment: @Johann, thank you for the kind offer!  No need -- if you want to cite this question on CS Stack Exchange, that's good enough for me -- I don't feel any need to be acknowledged in the paper.  I'm glad it was useful to you!